# ERROR: Expression doesn't produce a value in mongodb using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

```
    Imports MongoDB.Bson
    Imports MongoDB.Driver
    Imports MongoDB.Bson.IO
```

Code:

```
    Dim sQuery = Query.EQ("name", "abc")
    Dim sUpdate = Update.Set("title", "rocks")
    Dim sResult As SafeModeResult = tblBooksCustom.Update(sQuery , sUpdate )
```

It will not compile and it is failing on the `Update.Set` and gives the
following message:

> Expression does not produce a value.

Can anybody help me in solving this error.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem, Here is the vb.net code and hope this helps someone looking for it:

```
 Dim server As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost")
 Dim db As MongoDatabase = server("tutorial1")
 Dim books As MongoCollection(Of BsonDocument) = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument) ("bookdetails")

 Dim query = New QueryDocument() From {{"author", "Ernest Hemingway"}, {"title", "For Whom the Bell Tolls"}}
 Dim update = New UpdateDocument() From {{"$set", New BsonDocument("title", "Cat's Cradle")}}
 Dim updatedBook = books.Update(query, update)
```

Answer (score 1):

I test this code but no error

```
MongoClient mc = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

        MongoServer server = mc.GetServer();
        server.Connect();
        MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("testdb");

        MongoCollection<BsonDocument> col = db.GetCollection("mycollection");
        BsonDocument mycollection = new BsonDocument {
            { "name", "abc"},
            { "title", "b"}};
        col.Insert(mycollection);

        var sQuery = Query.EQ("name", "abc");
        var sUpdate = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.Set("title", "rocks");
        SafeModeResult sResult = col.Update(sQuery, sUpdate);
```

Can you test other new collection?